# Why does iPhone 6 have a thick line on its edge

Tags: hardware, iphone, design

[image: This gap is whatI'm talking about]

Apple never keeps even a dot on its hardware if it doesn't have a function. But why does the iPhone 6 have this Gap/Thick line on its edge? Any clue?

Comment: It's separating the parts of the external antenna. iPhone has WiFi/3G/LTE antennas and they need to be separated.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek: A bit like how comments and answers are ideally separated by this bit of white below:

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek You meant it's just a line? if you did, Nope! I have already got the answer I needed.

Comment: No I meant exactly what user3847746 has answered. But I couldn't find references co I wrota a comment.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Those are for the phones antennae (theres one towards the bottom of the phone as well).

The anodised aluminium causes really bad signal attenuation, hence the plastic-like strips are necessary to create a break in the metal shell.

I decided to delve a bit further and found that Apple is [trying to get rid of them.](http://www.cultofmac.com/326976/apples-new-material-will-eliminate-iphones-unsightly-antenna-lines/)

Comment: If Steve Jobs was around when they designed it, there wouldn't be a such a thing that spoils the whole beauty. Thanks for the answer man.

Comment: Check iPhone4 for example, it also has antennas separators (but smaller ;)

Comment: Yep the iPhone 4 does have them, slightly smaller and only a single one. This was what lead to the antennagate crisis of 2010 (signal loss would occur when the gap was bridged by a hand). iPhone 4s introduced dual antennae that could dynamically switch during calls which results in the two separators commonly seen today. Some more info here: http://blog.gsmarena.com/iphone-4s-dual-antennas-solve-antennagate-issue-bumpers-no-longer-required-to-make-calls/

Answer (score 2):

The reason is an antennae for the phone, since having a smooth iPhone would cause horrible and impossible coverage(quite literally). Since the iPhone has a lot of bands to cover as many network as possible, the "split" the metal back, and many of the strips on the device caused by this are the antenna.